How can I get the full logs of a truncated base64 string from Xcode?
I have a extremely long base64 string that I generated on my IOS app, I print it like this print(longBase64), Xcode printed it but its truncated in logs, this is what it looks like in the end of the base64 string
k+WP7PFGn/LX/wDV/k96uW8SyNCbdPJs0j8v93j/AFUX/LHyM8Y9d35nIp1<…>

as you can see, <...> is not a base64 character, means Xcode truncated it.
This is how I generate that base64 string
extension UIImage {
    func toBase64() -> String {
        return jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
    }
}

I want to see the whole base64 string so that I can use it on other things such as postman
The question is, how can I get that whole base64 string?

Write it to a file?

@matt that's a possible solution, but how can I write that on file? I'm running my app on a real device, is there a way to write from Xcode to my MacBook while running the app on the device?

You can easily write to a file on the device and then copy it to the MacBook.

You run the App on the device, but you launch it from XCode,
that is why you get the truncated print(...) in the console.
Similarly, given you temporarily disable the Sandbox,
you write to file, and it is created in your MacBook.
try base64String.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

Assuming you mean you want to be able to copy/paste the resulting Base64 string from Xcode to somewhere else...
Using your extension and this code:
    guard let img = UIImage(named: "test") else { return }
    let b64: String = img.toBase64()
    // just to see the string length in debug console
    print(b64.count)
    print()

Set a Breakpoint on the final print() line. When Xcode breaks, hover your mouse over the b64:

Click the "eye" icon at the right:

You can then click "Open With TextEdit" and you should have the entire string.
Note: If you are generating an "extremely long base64 string" it may take Xcode a long time to show that -- as in several seconds -- when you may think it has "hung" or failed.
I just tried it with print(b64.count) outputting 5001316 ... don't know if that's what you consider "extremely long."
